# Get content and class attribute value from child nodes of the DOM

Tags: php, dom

at first sorry of my bad english !

this is my simple cURL result :

```
<li class="result">
    <div class="song_info">
    <span class="artist_name">art1</span>
    <span class="song_name">name1</span>
    <span class="views">100 time</span>
          </div>
          </li>
//again 

<li class="result">
        <div class="song_info">
        <span class="artist_name">art2</span>
        <span class="song_name">name2</span>
        <span class="views">200 time</span>
              </div>
          </li>
```

and many like that ....

i used this code to extract values from html :

```
$classname = 'song_info';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // my html result .
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$get = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
$text = $get->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $text;
```

this code give me just first result :

```
art1
name1
100time
```

i want to get all results ! (Better in json)

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMXPath::query` method returns DOMNodeList. It implements Traversable interface, therefore you can loop through it with `foreach`. Rename `$get` variable to `$nodes`, so the variable will explicitly show what is stored in it. Then:

```
foreach ($nodes as $curNode) {
   $childNodes = $curNode->childNodes;

   foreach ($childNodes as $curChildNode) {
      // use $curChildNode->textContent to get content 
      // and $curChildNode->getAttribute('class') to get class name
   }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Then you should accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found My Answer

```
$text = $get->item(0)->nodeValue;   >> Give First Result

$text = $get->item(1)->nodeValue;   >> Give Second Result
```

I write a loop and receive all results :/